# Sharepoint approval form customization

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath, customization

I work for a global company that has a factory in Russia.
Headquarters gave us a SharePoint site and I made a "super-light" version of electronic document flow.

What I exactly want to do:
I have an approval form and I need to add their information from the Task form.
I thought about doing it one of 2 ways:

1. Add Description and Attachments to it. But I cannot add a column with URLs with attachments. I got only True\False (by string)
2. Add Web-form near approval form. But I got 404 not found.

My skill in programming is low. Has anyone done something like this before?

Workflow has only 1 thing "start approval process".

Screenshots added.
[image: Approval form]
[image: Task form]